# git push error: pack-objects died of signal 7

Tags: git, github

the command 'git push origin master' has unexpectedly stopped working. and returns the error 'error: pack-objects died of signal 7'

I'm trying to push to a github repo - it has been working for over a month and now has started to fail. at one point, my Google cloud vm ran out of memory and I had to expand it, which might roughly correlate to when this problem started (corrutpion maybe?). I resized everything after expanding my vm, and all seems to have gone well.

I am able to commit to my local repo, and no work is missing. I just can't seem to push to master on Github.

Any additional things I can try?

The more details from the error are below:

```
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug1: Sending command: git-receive-pack 'username/arcAnalytics_pjm.git'
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 1248153
fatal: failed to read object 42a2fd57f7bb45a4d1b9e2d6af2524900a0e1214: Input/output error
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 5 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r43 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3912, received 2816 bytes, in 7.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 539.3, received 388.2
debug1: Exit status 0
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:username/myrepo.git'
```

git fsck --full output:

```
error: unable to open .git/objects/0d: Input/output error
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: 42a2fd57f7bb45a4d1b9e2d6af2524900a0e1214: invalid sha1 pointer in cache-tree
broken link from    tree 00f3382345f0397c7c9f1ad36670551b36f97035
              to    tree 42a2fd57f7bb45a4d1b9e2d6af2524900a0e1214
dangling blob 001ed6037b627df0b782ba325350d2d91f3375c7
dangling blob 000a8ec7a524019cdf7d74c03f10da4022d46cbd
dangling blob 02f4fc9df4e232547909129159382b44d617833f
dangling blob 0332f78151d610e0fb5d0bc9a96fdf26bea2332e
dangling blob 07d8659b56652924ff4712daa24ee9b9c78f6a30
dangling commit 08c46465d834abb926c745eb6f07ded5eaa589f6
dangling commit 08160b7c7d159c4f0772d49a8a62d1244db1a1ca
dangling blob 08f21d9ee02e51a5b662c67ec7fdf83cda3161d4
dangling blob 099604b914d9198a9889a66ae217a6eda1f59468
dangling blob 0b7643506441f0a1ee6284b3e52e2a7c3bc34d37
dangling commit 0c483adf0b7f7ce728a9eafa6c04718ab4776662
dangling blob 0c8e84894efd393d224e7aa6a621e5cf2067ae20
dangling blob 0ca07d49214bb132b310523978faa45838b18a76
missing blob 135e2a70f0a6bfe1e4b5644ceaf8483bba3e1ae4
missing blob 132ab27e205db49b65fbf36c2ea8adb4ef3cf038
missing tree 173a73afdd8ff906f79e674df210f48ef8d4d460
missing blob 23060fb659bf5b39161e8335e5dae908167e1586
missing tree 313451223ac7a774f5efa61d71f5e9796e1ea431
missing blob 3580cbc8c2d4e7f1d4e3f93c8163611afb1a8acb
missing blob 3e12193bd64910751c59bd097c0d4404d4dce99d
missing tree 42a2fd57f7bb45a4d1b9e2d6af2524900a0e1214
missing blob 4a949b56d650d2316f6e583c8a5ccee88c7b69e5
missing blob 4e92ecbf2028938f98c6db09266221262740ce15
missing blob 57f475cec900b60b9d0262f163853e0d9b6cfd9b
missing blob 59bc4dd03586a7f1298c3e86eb1250a155cf87f4
missing blob 611a40be1bcc22bf65a133173501ee0618dbf71c
missing tree 64265aed212d020a0b976434f78e047da9328d98
missing blob 6556cc3e2625163e95ae0fc1a511992dbe8ece9b
missing blob 669eeff2a446abea5f9c189aeaadb53c469cf660
missing tree 6c14a600887d2d55b61e00bf971c9f0a752f3ffc
missing blob 6e303e2ee62c224699d8b0a4d7175390bb504a11
missing tree 7224ecf03af6fdc8ea6f344c8925379acbc735bd
missing blob 7824c5c52f580219c6ae3c4c460924762939ed43
missing blob 7d8810e8cf451c1af1bc44839ec2475fc2a68803
missing blob 82c0206af3dd667497ef94fcbf137c9870bf4735
missing blob 87d417dbd32eb295e3557ce60bf10bc1d6fb2b4f
missing blob 8b684bb949f65ec50e77d814f78cf0b2d26eb2d3
missing blob 8e5ac4cf687fc8090d422f72303403e7c8a7302a
missing blob 902cb00a90e647e5e747a1e9e82d1efbcaae1dd3
missing blob 99bed1bfec86026aa55969ccc72206de311d5879
missing blob 9be2e261dde5e05b8d88faa04d010d17b40b7694
missing blob 9e8cb4e2a21a396c5640c8c0b84191d1fdaea797
missing blob a9aea2028537194f86be20dc05a656f8f8a30b1d
missing blob b27ee11e621621b6f469956cf5b9a17eeed70c11
missing blob c0f8f720b6232fb4c8eb4468753c360a0eb0c6f8
missing blob ce8aa5c38a2e4fb692d94667790289f9be94a329
missing tree ce52f25dac0cdea1e5a699c7d03fb9f3fbca8618
missing blob d5e6443ea53a7ddaaa2282df9de62e3586c6e30d
missing commit d7b2f3cf22cc6c01ff08a1c8d0af0ce246b9e389
missing blob d7340b12bcceab99c93799c9f21b1436e57e64dd
missing blob e04c443467874736d9ef9176cd053da4abf67c9e
missing blob e2040fc0b063c9d43160506481843c9ba2a77713
missing blob f0a2702b4fa85618b0e5472ae36bfdcb7a241c7c
missing blob f3e4ed310cd29a2a396e40c17e29549a03e17adc
missing blob feca2b778fca2c3b15802803e4411e2c402f5946
dangling blob 0249ae0fb231815d7e0381d4e539b42664167fd6
dangling blob 024daff8f3404d2c9e48953a59c2758267e47017
dangling blob 04e1b22d721d5e7af8a0d2aa7bfed71084df8fb2
dangling blob 038bfe4ecf62a5113dc1beef066be54c620943fc
dangling blob 075dfa6af4f812f0456f8ed07df40fa930896c24
dangling blob 076fd620a364f27ae2bb732a52a5be455dbe931e
dangling blob 07f9a7b8e553a3834c504aefc9cb5f1f1cb16d39
dangling blob 08af80f74d44cf699f09ed3b903569d5418cf0c8
dangling blob 09b76a211c57b9fb05a884c4e9d2853e24c94aa0
missing blob 13c33cbaa7978079775fc02f91e5ad7c30d6b729
missing blob 15f7f967542c9dc03254b9f5060637cbe4f58ee5
missing blob 156d2cd7a1a9866fcb74f3635b92874c766e4517
missing blob 1f05cef5ce97f12af7b1f2501e8686fdde0b181f
missing blob 24657769b4944cf2fb6cb8e13c97daba23304361
missing blob 2c15306b04ceaadff915bbc9718c7c375321b089
missing blob 3cbd1810e3f53b989f131a805595522aa7944a9c
missing blob 413faabbf1111a4434b6b1d6ed1f2a643f07b30e
missing tree 4ce5fdecb610dca11c7e6d11a3b9bf83ed29ac46
missing blob 4f8d76cc2f2a1aae21824e8d4ca784a1bfa345c2
missing blob 4f570bc1bb94a96c509ff4074698f1026a75c88e
missing blob 5539136bcd2888c8488b366ec5cc53f502d0b2f3
missing blob 688f3c23096d9c79778e8b86c81b1acf334a90bf
missing blob 741521bfd7140e10f5feeaf8454e235bfcbef848
missing blob 7b155a13a591b21931bd3efa77661d2d00d129ce
missing tree 7dfd4d72ff2c3cc155a01c7df70656ac4484519c
missing blob 7e03d844ee593d79489c8a8c85fe7d87ddf0480f
missing tree 7ed7c91d49ea1718613e24e90a4bacc0d661a9e4
missing blob 811d9bd14921b057cbfbd498ad93f9d447c33a59
missing blob 88fd9c9b250c3e408ea283f5f811c619a6ff23f5
missing blob 8bc9e4e3e6e79c851798759f54de444940bf542e
missing blob aa159ec666c5cd50db876947f0107e4f7cf25e97
missing blob ae294fb2b2ee59d63ace72862644a8c3caade844
missing blob b17df125454cb21e6e1f6d7defa60da31a90f569
missing commit b28dff0d14ea211342bf1bd66bbb47a5f662119b
missing blob c0a1eef82d28214c85ea1e6642e32a7792ad6da9
missing blob c4251665bdefd4e5bea8abfe581af86d14265dd5
missing blob c739c6c54deb78a93f67111699796b5c57ab68a1
missing tree e729e322299e7286c03665a9c8d5506701373d1b
missing blob f0cf176a05a3255d7330f231f57aeefad2171ccc
missing blob f7113e1bfa954c7fd9960496cce9c304e2fcbae9
missing blob f76b917a1285ca4e7b8d5cc83c3fdffb30982024
missing tree fa5b16a2aacea9f942d0003870a507772d572308
missing blob fd459406a81fd8a002456ea7e7819016199fc3ae
missing blob ff995ac1a9dd69b8db32dc651686a61f819e32a9
```

Comment: Can you check git remote show origin?

Comment: On Linux, signal 7 is `SIGBUS`, a "bus error", generated when a program tries to touch memory it doesn't own (one of two such errors, `SIGSEGV` is perhaps more common for this). It suggests that `git pack-objects` itself is bad, but you might run `git fsck` first to see if there's some sort of data corruption tripping a bug in pack-objects.

Comment: @Christoph git remote show returns 'origin'

Comment: @torek I get a huge output of errors with git fsck --full. I added the output to my post.

Comment: OK, so it probably is some corrupted objects. This can be pretty hard to recover from. The usual advice is "use a Git repo that hasn't become corrupted", which means losing commits that you have that they don't... Edit: the first error (`error: unable to open .git/objects/0d: Input/output error`) is likely the biggest problem, it indicates that the file system itself is broken. Not Git's fault, but it may be triggering all the subsequent ones.

Comment: @torek ok looking into that now...

Comment: @torek I can navigate to the objects git is trying to open and I can open them in vim. The file system seems to be working properly. and now when I run the command I don't get the input/output errors.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. Maybe `git fsck` will get further now. BTW note that `dangling` commits and blobs are quite normal, it's the *missing* ones and the "broken link" and the thing flagged "error" that are actual issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190722/discussion-between-cam333-and-torek).